# What order do HTTP requests happen in relation to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, httprequest

I want to lazyload some of the images on a page. Therefore I need to put the image url into a data-url attribute, but my `<img>` tags are generated by wordpress:

So I'm thinking to use js to change my `<img>` tags before the page loads - **However**, will the HTTP requests for the images already have been made [or put in a queue] by the time my js script runs?

(I know its a rather hack solution, but I can't work out a better way to change the wordpress generated `<img>` tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering is synchronous, so yes, your images will have already been processed/requested by that point.  I found a really good resource for understanding this here:

http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_order_of_processing_scripts_and_style_sheets

I hope that helps.  :)

Comment: So even tho HTML spec is synchronous the speculative parsing by modern browsers will have made those requests. I see, thanks.